# Import jquery npm package in meteor client app

Tags: meteor, npm

I try to import the `jquery` npm package (it is already installed on the project) instead of the atmospherejs package but I would like to import it in the whole client part. I use the `btws:bootstrap` which needs jquery (with many others).

How can I manage to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use both Bootstrap and jQuery from npm.

Do this:

```
$ meteor remove twbs:boostrap
$ meteor npm install --save bootstrap
$ meteor remove jquery
$ meteor npm install --save jquery
```